# How to delete old MySQL user created by vault with auto rotation creds

Tags: devops, hashicorp-vault, ansible-vault, vault, hashicorp

Vault rotates creds and also create a user but when it creates a new user then it can’t delete the old user
These are my configuration
username=“user”
password=“password”

```
vault write database/roles/mysql-role
db_name=app1
creation_statements=“CREATE USER ‘{{name}}’@’%’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘{{password}}’;GRANT SELECT ON 
app1.* TO ‘{{name}}’@’%’;”

“revocation_statements”: [
“DROP USER ‘{{name}}’@’%’;”
]
```

Comment: What is the error? Did you `GRANT` Vault the rights to `DELETE USER` ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.